# Click to draw a shape (circle)

Tags: javafx

this code Draw a circle and I want to put a button that when I click on the button I can do  draw a circle. How Can I put Button for code below?

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    private Circle circle;
    private boolean firstClick = true;
    private double centerX, centerY;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Group root = new Group();
        circle = new Circle();
        circle.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        circle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        root.getChildren().add(circle);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        setHandlers(scene);

        primaryStage.setTitle("blank");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public void setHandlers(Scene scene) {
        scene.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            if (firstClick) {
                centerX = e.getX();
                centerY = e.getY();
                // sets the center
                circle.setCenterX(centerX);
                circle.setCenterY(centerY);
                // sets next "stage" of drawing your circle
                firstClick = false;
                // on second click will reset the process by setting firstClick to true
            }
            else {
                firstClick = true;
            }
        });

        scene.setOnMouseMoved(e -> {
            // will only evaluate on the first instance of a click
            if (!firstClick) {
                // Distance formula between center of circle and mouse pointer
                double c = Math
                        .sqrt(Math.pow(centerX - e.getX(), 2) + Math.pow(centerY - e.getY(), 2));
                circle.setRadius(c);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: don't see any code that tries to do what you want to achieve? Do some research (f.i. in your course book, external tutorials, api doc for the classes you want to use), apply what you learned, when stuck come back with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem

Comment: Maybe you should work through some JavaFX Tutorials. For example this one https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/button.htm#CJHEEACB and then ask remaining questions

Comment: I want to put a button and when I preesed it I can draw circle

Comment: I know Javafx But I cant handle this one. @Rosso

Comment: You replace your `Group` with a `HBox` and add the circle as well as a `Button` to the hbox. Whenever your Button is clicked you can update the visibility `setVisible(true|false)`of the circle

Comment: What kind of button? A standard button or a toggle button that has an on off state? “when I click on the button I can do draw a circle” -> what can you do if you don’t click the button? Will you eventually have other buttons with other functions?  What is your overall task?  Is it just to draw circles?  If so, what is the point of a button?  You can edit the question to explain if you want.

Comment: Yes,I have other functions. I am writing a paint program but I can draw shapes @jewelsea

Answer (score 2):

The following mre demonstrates the basic functionality you required :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DrawCircles extends Application {

    private Pane drawPane; //container for shapes
    private Circle clickedPoint;

    private static Color POINT_COLOR = Color.BLUEVIOLET, CIRCLE_COLOR = Color.RED;
    private static int POINT_RADIUS = 2;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        drawPane = new Pane(); //container for shapes

        root.setCenter(drawPane);

        Label help = new Label();
        ToggleButton draw = new ToggleButton("   Draw   ");
        draw.selectedProperty().addListener((ChangeListener<Boolean>) (obs, oldV, newV) -> {
            draw.setText(newV ? "Drawing" : "   Draw   ");
            help.setText(newV ? "Double click on one point. Double click on second point" : "");
        });

        HBox buttonBar = new HBox(10, draw, help);
        buttonBar.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_LEFT);
        root.setBottom(buttonBar);

        drawPane.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            if(!draw.isSelected()) return;
            if (event.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY) && event.getClickCount() == 2) {
                addPoint( event.getX() , event.getY());
            }
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Draw Circles");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void addPoint(double x, double y) {

        if(clickedPoint == null){ //no previously clicked point
            clickedPoint = new Circle(x, y, POINT_RADIUS, POINT_COLOR);
            drawPane.getChildren().add(clickedPoint); //mark clicked point

        }else{

            Shape shape = makeCircle(clickedPoint.getCenterX(), clickedPoint.getCenterY(), x, y);

            drawPane.getChildren().add(shape); //add line
            drawPane.getChildren().remove(clickedPoint);// remove first clicked point
            clickedPoint = null;
        }
    }

    private Shape makeCircle(double xCenter, double yCenter, double xEdge, double yEdge){

        double radius =Math.sqrt( Math.pow(xEdge - xCenter, 2) + Math.pow(yEdge - yCenter, 2));

        return new Circle(xCenter, yCenter, radius, CIRCLE_COLOR);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: you seem to be bored, doing foreign homework <g>

Comment: @kleopatra personally I learn best from examples. As Harry Truman once said: "I am from Missouri, show me". So this is how I try to help others where I can.